# SSH MaxSessions but not for whole system only for specific user

Tags: ssh, configuration, ssh-tunneling

I want to limit ssh tunnel, but not for all users in my system only for specific users 
`ssh maxSession` works for the whole system but I need a way to do it for specific users.
(don't suggest doing it in `/security/limits.conf` that don't apply to ssh sessions, only for ssh logins)

Comment: I don't think `maxSessions` does what you think it does

Comment: yes 
MaxSession doesnt work , i did ask chatgpt and it did answered me to set MaxStartups instead of Maxsession since Maxsession only work for session of shells not tunnels
but the problem is you cant set MaxStartup for specific user .

Comment: `MaxStartup` controls the number of simultaneous unauthenticated ssh sessions - basically, makes brute force attacks harder to accomplish

Comment: so do you have any idea how to limit ssh-tunneling's session which created by specific user?(e.g user 1 only be able to do 1 ssh tunneling session to server , user 2 be able to 2 ssh tunneling session to server)

Answer (score 1):

you would use the **Match** block feature within `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.
the contents of the Match block would have your desired `MaxSessions` value.  You would leave the original `MaxSessions` defined up above in the `sshd_config` file which would apply to everyone not defined for the Match block.

The Match block of text goes at the bottom of the `shd_config` file.

see https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sshd_config(5)

> Only a subset of keywords may be used on the linees following a Match keyword.  Available keywords are
>
> AcceptEnv, AllowAgentForwarding, AllowGroups, AllowStreamLocalForwarding, AllowTcpForwarding, AllowUsers, AuthenticationMethods, AuthorizedKeysCommand, AuthorizedKeysCommandUser, AuthorizedKeysFile, AuthorizedPrincipalsCommand, AuthorizedPrincipalsCommandUser, AuthorizedPrincipalsFile, Banner, ChrootDirectory, ClientAliveCountMax, ClientAliveInterval, DenyGroups, DenyUsers, DisableForwarding, ForceCommand, GatewayPorts, GSSAPIAuthentication, HostbasedAcceptedAlgorithms, HostbasedAuthentication, HostbasedUsesNameFromPacketOnly, IgnoreRhosts, Include, IPQoS, KbdInteractiveAuthentication, KerberosAuthentication, LogLevel, MaxAuthTries, MaxSessions, PasswordAuthentication, PermitEmptyPasswords, PermitListen, PermitOpen, PermitRootLogin, PermitTTY, PermitTunnel, PermitUserRC, PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms, PubkeyAuthentication, RekeyLimit, RevokedKeys, RDomain, SetEnv, StreamLocalBindMask, StreamLocalBindUnlink, TrustedUserCAKeys, X11DisplayOffset, X11Forwarding and X11UseLocalhost.

```
# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis

Match User anoncvs
       X11Forwarding no
       AllowTcpForwarding no
       PermitTTY no
       ForceCommand cvs server
       MaxSessions 1

Match User ron
       MaxSessions 1

Match User bob
       MaxSessions 1
```

from the freebsd link above

> 

Comment: does maxsession apply to "ssh tunnel" session ?
cause I still can do 2 ssh tunnel session after I did add that line for my user.
(my os is ubuntu)

Comment: i did test something i set  maxlogin for a user to 1 in /etc/security/limits.conf
and max session in sshd_config to 1
when i open 1 normal ssh session ( in my case with powershell ) with device 1
i can not make another ssh tunneling ssh to server with device .
so that's work perfectly.
but when i close normal ssh session in device 1 , i can still do ssh tunneling session in device 1 and 2 simultaneously!

Comment: updated answer, see above.

Comment: i'm not super familiar with ssh tunneling, but it looks like you can enforce user specific tunnel settings using the `Match` thing in sshd_config, with `PermitTunnel` anyway.

Comment: if you screw up, the `service sshd start` will fail so that's how you'll know if it's supported or not.  Be sure to maintain a backup working copy of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` when messing with this.

Comment: i don't know if *MaxSessions applies to SSH Tunnel*.

Comment: it doesnt apply to it , i did test it